# How to get property info by using the Typescript language service

Tags: typescript, languageservice

How to get the type of a property of an object with Typescript 1.4.0.

I'm searching for something similar to C# it has the possibility to look up the properties of an object.

```
var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
foreach( var property in properties){}
```

What I have so far is:

```
var ls = ts.createLanguageService(host, ts.createDocumentRegistry())
var nav = ls.getNavigationBarItems(host.fileName);
```

Given the example Interface:

```
interface Example {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    age: string;
}
```

The TypeScript language service returns the result:

```
{  
   "NavigationBarItems":[  
      {  
         "text":"Example",
         "kind":"interface",
         "kindModifiers":"",
         "spans":[  
            {  
               "start":0,
               "length":83
            }
         ],
         "childItems":[  
            {  
               "text":"age",
               "kind":"property",
               "kindModifiers":"",
               "spans":[  
                  {  
                     "start":69,
                     "length":12
                  }
               ],
               "childItems":[  

               ],
               "indent":0,
               "bolded":false,
               "grayed":false
            },
            {  
               "text":"firstname",
               "kind":"property",
               "kindModifiers":"",
               "spans":[  
                  {  
                     "start":24,
                     "length":18
                  }
               ],
               "childItems":[  

               ],
               "indent":0,
               "bolded":false,
               "grayed":false
            },
            {  
               "text":"lastname",
               "kind":"property",
               "kindModifiers":"",
               "spans":[  
                  {  
                     "start":47,
                     "length":17
                  }
               ],
               "childItems":[  

               ],
               "indent":0,
               "bolded":false,
               "grayed":false
            }
         ],
         "indent":0,
         "bolded":false,
         "grayed":false
      }
   ]
}
```

The information I'm missing is the type (string,number,Map<>,any) and if it is an array or object e.g.

```
"text":"lastname",
"kind":"property",
"type":"string",  //string,number,Map<>,any
```

Any Idea how to achieve this?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution, don't know how I missed it in the first place. [Nicholas Wolverson](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/01/20/typescript-compiler-api.html) has an excelent blog post about it. Using the TypeScript language service was not the correct choice. The correct solution is to use the TypeScript compiler API.

```
var program = ts.createProgram([dummyScriptName], host.getCompilationSettings(), host);
var typeChecker = program.getTypeChecker();
var sf = program.getSourceFile(dummyScriptName);
var decls = sf.getNamedDeclarations().map(function (nd) { return nd.symbol.name + ": " + typeChecker.typeToString(typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(nd)); });
```

This will return the needed information

```
interface Person {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    age: number[];
}
```

result:

```
Person: Person
firstname: string
lastname: string
age: number[]
```

please use ([code](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/nwolverson/assets/tsc/blog.js), [mirror_code](https://gist.github.com/chrisber/9354ef8327e8fbc8b89e), [blog post](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2015/01/20/typescript-compiler-api.html)) for details.

Comment: https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript does those tool tips just fine using lasagne service "getQuickInfo"

Comment: Also you can get the program from the language service method 'getProgram'

Comment: Your are absolutely right. I can use getQuickInfoAtPosition to get the info I need but its a little bit uncomfortable to lookup every item at its position. Thanks for the note for `getProgram`, do you know if I need to implement the compiler host when I want to use `getProgram`? Or can I stay with languageservicehost?

Comment: Just langaugeServiceHost

Comment: Did a quick check. `getProgram` is coming in TS version 1.5. Not there in 1.4 yet.

Comment: I don't think it works anymore given I think getNamedDeclarations was removed