# Way to view/print a resolved TypeScript type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, visual-studio-code, typescript-generics

I am looking for a way to view the types that TypeScript resolves the declared types to (ie. for Generics). I use VS Code, and oftentimes a Union or Intersection or other Generic results in the mouseover having information such as:

```
(property) Workspace: Pick<{
    __typename?: "a" | undefined;
} & {
    __typename?: "b" | undefined;
} & Pick<typeA, "id" | ... 4 more ... | "state"> & {
    ...;
}, "__typename" | ... 4 more ... | "state"> & Pick<...>
```

And I know that VS Code must have the full type information, because when I try to use the type incorrectly, I'll get an error like `Property 'goo' does not exist on type '...'`

I'm hoping there's either a way to do this with some sort of `console.log(someUtilityFunction(type))` or some vscode setting or extension?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get property info by using the Typescript language service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28692515/how-to-get-property-info-by-using-the-typescript-language-service)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683303/how-can-i-see-the-full-expanded-contract-of-a-typescript-type)